# How to set the opacity of an image in a frameset which is in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I put a div transparent box(done by css) in my main html. And then in the box, I put an iframe linked to another frameset made up of four frames.

```
<div class="box">
<h1>World Map</h1>
<iframe style="border:2px solid black;" src="map/mapframes.html" width="75%" height="960"></iframe>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div.box {
display: block;
margin: auto;
width: 85%;
margin-top: 50px;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid black;
opacity: 0.95;
filter: alpha(opacity=95);
z-index: 5;
font-family: Arial;
text-align: center;
}
```

One of the frames is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<img src="img/s.png" width="1125" height="558.5">
</body>
</html>
```

which is a normal code for nothing but a single image. However, since it is in the frameset which is in the div, its opacity is affected as well. What can I do to make sure the image opacity is set to 1.00, while the rest of the content are still 0.95 as the div box?

Answer (score 0):

use this in css:

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
```

the first 3 numbers are the color you want to have in the background in rgb format, "1" is the opacity of the background, change it to anything between 0-1!

I hope I helped! let me know if I did!

EDIT: remove:
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.95;

and add:

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
```

in div.box {}

Comment: Hello, which layer should I use this on? The main Html, the iframe, the frameset or the frame itself? Thanks for the help.